# Barcode4J on Android ( missing BufferedImage support )

Tags: java, android, barcode-printing, barcode4j

I have been trying to use Barcode4J on Android but I can not seem to get BufferedImage class and I am not sure how I am suppose to replace this class with anything from Android.graphic.* which does not seem to have something similar. Also the Barcode4J will not accept anything other then BufferedImage object for obvious reasons.
What could I use instead or is there a Barcode generator Lib better suited for Android?

I have tried Barcode4Android which really made no sense since the Example they gave on GIT used BufferedImage from the java.awt.image.BufferedReader package also >.< . So I was back at step 1.

I actually just need the QR generating function.

My Questions.
1. Is there an Alternative to Barcode4J for Android.
2. OR is there a work around for my problem ?

Here is one of the Java tutorials I tried to use

```
public class HelloExample1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //Create the barcode bean
    Code39Bean bean = new Code39Bean();

    final int dpi = 150;

    //Configure the barcode generator
    bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(1.0f / dpi)); //makes the narrow bar, width exactly one pixel
    bean.setWideFactor(3);
    bean.doQuietZone(false);

    //Open output file
    File outputFile = new File("resources"+"/"+"images"+"/"+"out.png");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    try {

        //Set up the canvas provider for monochrome PNG output
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
            out, "image/x-png", dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);

        //Generate the barcode
        bean.generateBarcode(canvas, "Hello World");

        //Signal end of generation
        canvas.finish();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would love to know a solution for this problem, i suggested Zxing, its a great tool, but in my case i need Code4J because Zxing doesn't supports EAN128 codes for the moment. Someone knows how to solve BadaBoomphs question about BufferedImage?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/README.md), its a code generator and reader, easy to use in Android. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not easy to use in Android unless you want to use it as an external app. Even doing that is poorly documented.